# VWP or B2 for short stay in US on way to Canada?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, us-visa-waiver-program

My family and I (Australian citizens) are travelling to Canada for 4 months, with a stop-over in the US for 3 days. Our return flight leaves direct from Canada, we will not be transiting through the US on our way back to Australia.
As Australian citizens, can we just enter the US on the Visa Waiver Programme or will we need to get a B2 visa? It sounds like legally we need a B2, but anecdotally a VWP may be fine..? It is quite costly and inconvenient to get a B2 visa for just 3 days, but my partner is quite risk-averse especially given the tightened Immigration into the US..! 
Any recent experiences would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[US embassy in the UK](https://uk.usembassy.gov/visas/non-immigrant-visa-faqs/visa-waiver-program-and-esta/) says this:

> If I enter the United States visa free under the Visa Waiver Program,
> can I then travel to Canada/Mexico/ Bermuda or the islands in the
> Caribbean?
>
> Yes, provided you have a return or onward ticket. If your return
> journey will take you back through the United States, even if only in
> transit, the total trip, including both periods of time spent in the
> United States/Canada/Mexico Bermuda, or the islands in the Caribbean
> cannot exceed 90 days. If it does, you will require a visa.

From the [USA Governments travel website](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visa-waiver-program.html) it states this:

> If you are admitted to the United States under the VWP, you may take a
> short trip to Canada, Mexico, or a nearby island and generally be
> readmitted to the United States under the VWP for the remainder of the
> original 90 days granted upon your initial arrival in the United
> States. Therefore, the length of time of your total stay, including
> the short trip, must be 90 days or less.

So the main government travel website only takes about readmission for short stays in nearby countries and islands. The answers are quite conflicting, and conflicting with what the Australian US embassy says.

**Update 9th February 2018**

I emailed U.S. Customs and Border Protection and got this response.

> Response Via Email (CBP Officer)  02/09/2018 06:14 AM
>
> Hello,   We
> recommend that you apply for a visa if your trip to Canada/Mexico/
> Bermuda or the islands in the Caribbean exceeds 90 days.
>
> Regards, ESTA Team

Looks like it's best to get a visa, this comes directly from a CBP officer.

Comment: Interesting. That's the first time I've seen that written in any official place. Usually it's understood that border guards have discretion to not require a visa for two transits 90+ days apart, and use it most of the time when it's clear the applicant is not intending to stay in the US for a long period.

Comment: @DJClayworth Common sense would probably prevail in most cases but definitely not worth the risk of being denied entry and impacting future travel to or through The United States.

Comment: Then I have to go and edit some of my other answers here.

Comment: That's interesting - the answer is a bit different on the Australian version of the website.

Comment: "I am transiting through the U.S. on my way to another country. Can I use VWP?
Yes, as long as your total stay in the US, Canada, Mexico and adj islands is less than 90 days, and you meet the other VWP requirements. You can use the VWP if, for instance, you are transiting the U.S. on a journey between Aus and Eur.
However, if for example you are transiting the U.S. on the way to a six-month stay in Canada, you cannot use the VWP, as your total time in the US, Canada, Mexico and the adj islands will be over 90 days. In this case you should apply for a B-1/B-2 visitor visa, or a transit visa."

Comment: Sorry, don't know how to copy and paste from links!

Comment: @MoxieB updated answer but its not finished yet, you could try calling the US embassy in Australia (02) 6214-5600 and posting your response as an answer here. I have emailed U.S. Customs and Border Protection and will post the answer I get in my answer, they can take up to 14 business days to   reply though.

Comment: The embassy no refers you onto a visa call centre who also give conflicting information but have said to get B2 just in case... I've also emailed but got a generic response to refer to the website...

Comment: My thinking is that the US don't (or shouldn't) have any control over another country's borders - if we don't come back to the US within the 90 days, what does it matter if we stay in Canada for 120 days?

Comment: @MoxieB a CBP officer got back to me quickly, updated my answer with their reply, looks like its best to get a visa to avoid problems with future travel to the USA. The only alternative to costly Visas for 3 days would be trying to get to Canada without visiting the US? Don't know your full situation so don't know if that is applicable.

Comment: I agree with you @MoxieB about us having control over that. I can understand stopping people crossing into Canada to reset their 90days but a CBP officer should be able to see that from their records if someone tries to do this.

Comment: Rerouting is an option we're looking into, as is possibly a short trip to Iceland to get out of North America..! Rather spend the money on a trip than going into State Dept coffers...

Comment: Thanks for the info Sam, yes, have to weigh up options as it seems B2 seems the safest

Comment: @MoxieB seems the only option really if you insist on going through the USA but yes id be tempted to go somewhere else. You're welcome, don't forget to accept the answer if you think it's right :)